# Getting Error with ##TempTable

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables, openquery

I want to use `##TempTable` to get value from oracle db in my sql Server query, but always get error, the error says

```
##TempTable is Invalid object name '##TempTable '.
```

here's the code where I use `##TempTable`

```
SET @sQuery = 'SELECT * INTO ##TempTable 
FROM OPENQUERY(ITCP,''SELECT * FROM DB.WINFO WHERE SCH_DATE = '''''+ 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@DDATE,121) +''''''' ) A' EXEC(@sQuery)
```

I confused, Should I Declare Query to create the `##TempTable` like create Table like usual or by that query the temp table should automatically created? because I always getting error

Comment: Does it work if you create ##TempTable in advance and do an `INSERT INTO ##TempTable SELECT *...`?

Comment: Yes,it works but i'm afraid later i didnt know the structure of ora db i couldn't create the table first, is it possible to do query like that insert into ##sometable from openquery?

Comment: Just to confirm - you're getting error in above `EXEC(@sQuery)` or elsewhere?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter yes in EXEC(@sQuery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is your temp table is being created in one scope, and your dynamic query is being executed in another.

A few things to try:

1. Create the ##temptable first, then populate it in your dynamic query.
2. Try prefixing the table name with tempdb.. (so tempdb..##temptable).
3. Use a persistent table (not a temp table).

Hope this helps.

Comment: hmm I see, so its better to create DB like tempdb did, by just drop value from oracle to prevent those error, and keep my primary db clear from any temporary table.

Comment: Actually ## is a global temp table that should be visible in all scopes. Oh and especially during creation